# Are one photon at-a-time experiments regarded as the Quantum versions of Classical experiments?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, visible-light

Is it a correct distinction to regard classical experiments conducted *one photon at-a-time* as the quantum version of the experiments? For instance, if we take Young's original double-slit, and convert it to a one photon (or electron) at-a-time version of the experiment with a CCD backplate, is it now properly a *quantum* double-slit experiment? Or are experiments considered quantum, e.g. the quantum eraser experiment, only because of the model used for its interpretation?

Comment: I don't know what a "quantum version" of any experiment is supposed to be. The *world* is quantum, and in some cases we get away with modelling it by classical physics, but there is no property of experiments being "classical" or "quantum", and I don't know what makes you think there is.

Comment: I'm afraid this is likely to be closed as primarily opinion-based. Offering my own opinion-based answer, there seem to be multiple concepts of what requirements should be satisfied for an experiment to be considered "quantum". One prevalent view (e.g. in optics) is that "quantum" phenomena are difficult/impossible to explain without the notion of quanta. Another, probably orthogonal, and equally prevalent viewpoint (e.g. in quantum info), is that "quantum" phenomena must violate a Bell inequality or otherwise be inexplicable without entanglement present. (FYI, I don't agree with either.)

Comment: @ACuriousMind, what made me think there's a distinction is that there's an experiment officially called "the Quantum Eraser experiment," though Fresnel and Arago conducted literally the same experiment two hundred years ago, but with normal intensity light.

Comment: FWIW, I have saved myself much confusion of this sort by deciding that people apply the words 'quantum' and 'classical' in completely different and often contradictory ways, and as such just ignoring such language unless the author in question defines precisely what they mean.

Comment: @Rococo, yes I should've included that option too, i.e. that there's no correlation at all and physicists' usage of the two terms varies.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, it'd be great to have some follow-up from you. You imply that to even posit such a distinction is worthy of punishment, but Anna V seems to think that just such a distinction exists. So is she wrong, or are you?

Comment: Every experiment that you have ever done or heard of was a quantum mechanical experiment. In some cases one needs quantum theory to explain the outcome and in some others one doesn't. That's the only difference.

Comment: Every experiment is a quantum mechanical experiment. Classical mechanics can explain some of them, but quantum mechanics can explain _all_ of them. That's how you should be sayin' it. But you couldn't legitimately say such a thing before the quantum eraser experiment.

Answer (score 1):

In the classical electromagnetic theory the word "photon" has no meaning. Nature as we know it from our experiments is basically "quantum" , i.e. it follows the equations and [postulates of quantum mechanics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html). The equations and laws of classical mechanics can be shown to emerge from the quantum mechanical underlying framework.

Classical mechanics is very successful in describing macroscopic observations, from planetary orbits to ballistics etc, and classical electrodynamics describe perfectly electromagnetic waves.

Quantum mechanical mathematical treatments become necessary when the dimensions in the problem are commensurate with the [Heisenberg Uncertainty principle](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html), which can have various [other forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Additional_uncertainty_relations). This usually imposes small dimensions for quantum mechanical phenomena, as h_bar is such a small number that for macroscopic problems it is within measurement errors equal to zero, and so the HUP is fulfilled.

The concept of a photon does not exist for a classical electromagnetic wave, thus a photon's (x,y,z,t) is necessarily described by quantum mechanical equations which give the probability of its existence in space time. Working with single photons is a quantum mechanical experiment.

In general working with individual atoms, molecules, elementary particles needs quantum mechanical formulations. Macroscopic quantum mechanical solutions are necessary when some pair of  the observables  modeling the problem are constrained by the HUP, as with [superconductivity](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v371/n6498/abs/371594a0.html) for example.

Comment: Thank you, Anna. You seem to be offering a very definite criterion for the distinction I mention. I like your answer and plan to accept it as the answer after I look into some of the things you mention.

Comment: I'd just like to add that it's really the action *per particle* which should be on the order of $\hbar$ in order for QM to be necessary. This is why we still see collective quantum phenomena such as BEC, even though the overall action scale of the system is orders of magnitude larger than $\hbar$.

Comment: @MarkMitchison  thanks for the addition. I was trying to think of  how to include superconductivity but ended up with arcane Heisenberg pairs of observables .